# Difference between logspace generators

Tags: c++, math, optimization, fftw

Looking through ncmpcpp's spectrum visualizer code, I found a [method](https://github.com/ncmpcpp/ncmpcpp/blob/417d7172e5587f4302f92ea6377268dca7f726ad/src/screens/visualizer.cpp#L614) that generates a "logspace," a vector used to group frequencies into log-scaled bins after applying an fft.

Here is the (isolated) code:

```cpp
// Lowest frequency in display
const double HZ_MIN = 20;
// Highest frequency in display
const double HZ_MAX = 20000;
// Number of bars in spectrum
const size_t width = 100;

std::vector<double> dft_logspace;


void GenLogspace() {
    // Calculate number of extra bins needed between 0 HZ and HZ_MIN
    const size_t left_bins = (log10(HZ_MIN) - width*log10(HZ_MIN)) / (log10(HZ_MIN) - log10(HZ_MAX));
    // Generate logspaced frequencies
    dft_logspace.resize(width);
    const double log_scale = log10(HZ_MAX) / (left_bins + dft_logspace.size() - 1);
    for (size_t i = left_bins; i < dft_logspace.size() + left_bins; ++i) {
        dft_logspace[i - left_bins] = pow(10, i * log_scale);
    }
}
```

I spent a while trying to understand how this works... and it seems to be an awfully complicated way to get the same result as the following function, which works the way you'd expect:

Given limits `a` and `b` so that `a < b`, divide the interval `[log10(a), log10(b)]` into equal subintervals and exponential-map your way back.

```cpp
// a = HZ_MIN, and
// b = HZ_MAX

void my_GenLogspace() {
    dft_logspace.resize(width);

    // Generate log-scaled frequency bins between HZ_MAX and HZ_MIN
    for (size_t i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        dft_logspace[i] = HZ_MIN * pow((HZ_MAX/HZ_MIN), ((double) i/(width-1)));
    }
}
```

I'm fairly sure that these are mathematically identical.

Are they? Is there any reason to use original method over my rewrite? Does the author of the commit that introduced this code know something I don't?

---

Edit: `(width-1)`, per Bob__'s suggestion

Comment: Well, your solution seems a bit [off](https://godbolt.org/z/8a3hxj9rs).

Comment: Try with [`(double) i/(width - 1)`](https://godbolt.org/z/ab87M3jv9). BTW, I have no idea what they are trying to achive in the first snippet.

Comment: `(width-1)` doesn't quite match their output, either... though it's pretty close. My hypothesis is that their `logspace` starts at `0`, while mine starts at `HZ_MIN`.

This doesn't seem to make much of a difference, but it might matter with a higher low bound...

Answer (score 0):

Got it. If anyone happens to need this later...

```cpp
// Generate log-scaled vector of frequencies from HZ_MIN to HZ_MAX
void GenLogspace() {
    // Prepare vector
    dft_logspace.resize(width);

    // Calculate number of extra bins needed between 0 HZ and HZ_MIN

    // In logspace, divide the region between MAX and MIN into
    // w - 1 equal segments (by fencepost, this gives us w seperators)
    const double d = (
        (log10(HZ_MAX) - log10(HZ_MIN))
        /
        (width - 1)
    );

    // Count how many of these segments will fit between
    // 0 and MIN (note that we're still in logspace).
    // This is how many log-scaled intervals are outside
    // our desired range of frequencies.
    const size_t skip_bins = log10(HZ_MIN) / d;

    // Calculate log scale size.
    // We can't use the value of d here, because d is "anchored" to both MIN and MAX.
    // The last bin should be equal to MAX, but there may not be a bin that is equal to MIN.
    //
    // So, we re-partition our logspace:
    // Divide the distance between 0 and MAX into equal partitions.
    const double log_scale = log10(HZ_MAX) / (skip_bins + width - 1);

    // Exponential-map bins out of logspace, skipping those that are outside our range.
    // Note that the first (skipped) bin is ALWAYS 1, since 10^0 = 1.
    // The last bin ALWAYS equals MAX.
    for (size_t i = skip_bins; i < width + skip_bins; ++i) {
        dft_logspace[i - skip_bins] = pow(10, i * log_scale);
    }
}
```